# ffmpeg install with libmp3lame fails on Mojave and high Sierra

Tags: macos, installation, ffmpeg, lame

I have tried installing ffmpeg using `brew install ffmpeg --enable-libmp3lame` as well as `brew install ffmpeg --with-libmp3lame` and both versions fail.  The error I receive is `Error: invalid option: --enable-libmp3lame`.  I would love to know what I am doing wrong.

I am trying to install this on 3 different machines that just had clean installs of either OSX Mojave or OSX High Sierra.  The only item I have installed so far is home-brew.

Answer (score 1):

[Since February 2019 (version 2.0)](https://brew.sh/2019/02/02/homebrew-2.0.0/), Homebrew does not offer options for its formulae anymore.

To get FFmpeg with LAME through Homebrew, you simply have to install:

```
brew install ffmpeg
```

It comes with LAME by default. If you need additional, non-free encoders or custom options, have a look at [this tap](https://github.com/varenc/homebrew-ffmpeg).